# ServiceStack V4 API Documentation missing response types (in lists)

Tags: c#, servicestack

We are trying to convert from Swagger to use the native metadata feature of SSV4. But in doing so, there have been issues with the api generation:

The issue appears to be in the internal SS operation BaseMetadataHandler .GetMetadataTypesForOperation(...), which does not seem to detect the complex types in a List (and associate them with an operation). For example, this request / response dto will not show the documentation for "ComplexType":

```
[Route("/example", "GET")]  
    [DataContract]  
    public class Example : IReturn<Example Response>  
    {  
        [ApiMember(IsRequired = true)]  
        [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]  
        public Guid ExampleGuid { get; set; }  
    }  

    [DataContract]  
    public class ExampleResponse : IHasResponseStatus  
    {  
        [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = false)]
        public List<ComplexType> Results{ get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = false)]
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }

    }
```

If the "ComplexType" is singular (not in a list), the type is documented correctly in metadata pages. Am I configuring these DTOs incorrectly? Or maybe the metadata engine?

Thanks in advance... Jordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've expanded ServiceStack's metadata pages to include referenced Types in Generic and Array collections [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/804922c48cf61413b08160c46e255e722fa27d1b).

This change is available from ServiceStack **v4.0.32+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Tested on our implementation and it works as expected. Thanks so much... made my day!

Comment: Hi @mythz - I'd like to reopen this issue with you if possible... as confirmed before it works fine for the first level of Generic arrays... but if there multiple layers of array, the Metadata pages does not display info for the class. 

In my example above, consider the type "ComplexType" containing a member that had another generic List in it of "ComplexType2". In that case, ComplexType2 would not be shown in the Metadata pages. 

The check you do almost needs to be recursive or something fancy like that? Thanks again,

Comment: @jglassco please open a new issue at: https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues and include the models that repro's the issue.